Simply Adjusting the Position of Dashed Lines in Nicematrix Package
I encountered a problem with the horizontal dashed line created by the nicematrix package in LaTeX. The line is a little close to the bottom of the matrix, overlapping with the elements of the second row.
Is there any simple and default solution in nicematrix to adjust the dashed line position which don't need to tweak detailed parameters?

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, bm, color, framed, graphicx, hyperref, mathrsfs}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\begin{document}

$\begin{bNiceArray}{c|[tikz=dashed,color=red]c}
    {\widetilde{\bm{\Sigma}}_{11}} & {\widetilde{\bm{\Sigma}}_{12}}\\
    \Hline[tikz=dashed,color=red]
    {\widetilde{\bm{\Sigma}}_{21}} & {\widetilde{\bm{\Sigma}}_{22}}
\end{bNiceArray}$

\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SX! Try to enlarge the space between cells with something like cell-space-limits = 2pt.

As said by jlab in comment, you can use the key cell-space-top-limit (or the key cell-space-limits which fixes both cell-space-top-limit and cell-space-bottom-limit).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, bm, color, framed, graphicx, hyperref, mathrsfs}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\begin{document}

$\begin{bNiceArray}{c|[tikz=dashed,color=red]c}[cell-space-top-limit=2pt]
    {\widetilde{\bm{\Sigma}}_{11}} & {\widetilde{\bm{\Sigma}}_{12}}\\
    \Hline[tikz=dashed,color=red]
    {\widetilde{\bm{\Sigma}}_{21}} & {\widetilde{\bm{\Sigma}}_{22}}
\end{bNiceArray}$

\end{document}


If you prefer, you can apply that parameter to the second row only by using the key cell-space-top-limit of the command \RowStyle:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, bm, color, framed, graphicx, hyperref, mathrsfs}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\begin{document}

$\begin{bNiceArray}{c|[tikz=dashed,color=red]c}
    {\widetilde{\bm{\Sigma}}_{11}} & {\widetilde{\bm{\Sigma}}_{12}}\\
    \Hline[tikz=dashed,color=red]
\RowStyle[cell-space-top-limit=2pt]{}
    {\widetilde{\bm{\Sigma}}_{21}} & {\widetilde{\bm{\Sigma}}_{22}}
\end{bNiceArray}$

\end{document}



Try to add \NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits=2pt} (as suggested @
jlab in his comment) and option [margin=2pt]:
\documentclass[margin=3mm, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, bm}

\begin{document}
$
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits=2pt} % <---
\begin{bNiceArray}{c|[tikz=dashed,color=red]c}[margin=2pt]% <---
    {\widetilde{\bm{\Sigma}}_{11}} & {\widetilde{\bm{\Sigma}}_{12}}\\
    \Hline[tikz=dashed,color=red]
    {\widetilde{\bm{\Sigma}}_{21}} & {\widetilde{\bm{\Sigma}}_{22}}
\end{bNiceArray}
$
\end{document}

After three compilation the result is the following:

